# How to use feature detection to know if browser supports css hover?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, feature-detection

How can I use feature detection to determine whether a browser supports the :hover pseudo class? I want to do this WITHOUT using conditional comments to include ie6-specific script files if possible.

Comment: For feature detection, you would need some complex Javascript, which seems like a pretty big dependency - especially seeing as the one and (AFAIK) only browser that doesn't support :hover is indeed IE6

Comment: In theory, you could set a style on the `body:hover` and then get the computed style for the body and see if it is set. I suspect that would break if the pointer was on the toolbar though. That said, if you are using `:hover` for anything more then an indication that it is worth clicking at the point the pointer is at, then you should probably be looking at JS anyway. `:hover` is just too limiting and tends to mean you have a dependency on people using a pointing device, and on being able to hold it steady (difficult with, for example, arthritis).

Comment: pretty much every major, modern browser supports the :hover pseudo class

Comment: @David - that's a good thought, but as you pointed out, it won't work if the mouse is outside the window when the script runs

Answer (score 1):

If it is ie6 or older, it doesn't support hover.  Any other browsers that don't support hover are too old and obscure to worry about.

***EDIT***

It is possible to make `:hover` work in ie 6: [See here](http://www.danvega.org/blog/index.cfm/2008/1/1/CSS-hover-selector)

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly the kind of answer I was NOT looking for

Comment: Everyone's been harping on feature detection over browser detection lately, so I was trying to do my due diligence to go that route. However, it seems I may have to just check for IE6 and do the jquery wireup.

Comment: @Mark Hildreth, in general feature detection is better, but some features are extremely hard or impossible to detect.  For example: The ie6 png transparency bug, which I pretty sure is undetectable.

Answer (score 1):

The :hover pseudo-class is supported by standards compliant browsers. Browsers like IE6 will only support it for `<a>` elements.

You can however use hover changes on any thing using jQuery, to name one.

```
$('.class').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

In your css, use the class .hover in place of the pesudo-class :hover

Comment: I love how someone always gives a jQuery solution, even when it isn't asked for.

Comment: I find it's the cleanest way to simulate hover support for all browsers. And I've actually answered his question with a working solution ;)

Comment: it isn't very helpful for someone working on a non-jquery project.  It is definitely not the cleanest fix; there are fixes that actually make `:hover` work in ie6.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I see where you're coming from from. The reason I use the solution I've shown is that it's platform agnostic, and I find code easier to maintain when it's as standard as possible. I consider javascript libraries to be exactly that, and not a separate paradigm. I concede that if you're already loading other libraries, you might not want to involve jQuery in addition.

Comment: @puppybard - Good suggestion. However, We're already using jquery, so that's not a problem. However, we have to wire up the hover event to an extremely large number (like 400+) elements on the page. Using jquery to do this requires almost a full second to do this in jquery 1.4.3+. It was significantly faster (and in an acceptable range) in older versions of jquery. What I would like to do is include the css rules for hover, then only run the jquery wire-up (as you suggested) if the browser doesn't support :hover and side-step the whole problem.